# GWT DragStartEvent vs MouseDownEvent

Tags: gwt, drag-and-drop

I use plain legacy GWT DnD rather than gwt-dnd library (because I don't need to DnD widgets, but plain data, so I want to keep it simple).
I could implement it with an Image widget for the source.
Then I switched to HTML widget, but then Drag does not work: no error no nothing, simply the drag doesn't drag anymore.
The code (the issue being on the drag part, I list below only this part of the code):

```
HTML theWidget = new HTML("some string");  // NOK : doesn't drag
// Image theWidget = new Image ("path/image.png");  // OK : does drag

theWidget.addDragStartHandler(new DragStartHandler() {  
        public void onDragStart(DragStartEvent event) {  
            event.setData(data, "some data" );  
        }  
});
```

What's wrong ?
It looks like there is no DragStartEvent because after I click for drag and move the mouse to drop target, the browser selects what is in between (drag start to drop target).

For investigation, I added a MouseDownHandler, and indeed a MouseDownEvent  fires.

So the question is :  how is it possible to control which event GWT will fire between DragStartEvent and MouseDownEvent ?

Comment: What about the browser? Have you tried to simply `preventDefault()` the `DragStartEvent`?

Comment: @andrea-boscolo : I tested on Firefox and chrome up to now (probably same : both include webkit). I want to prevent MouseDown. I don't get your proposal : how could I prevent MouseDown --assuming then I would get DragStart -- Tx

Comment: @andrea-boscolo : I have added event.preventDefault(); to my MouseDownHandler. It does not prevent MouseDown to fire. However there is no more the selection from MouseDown to MouseUp.  So my conclusion is that it prevents the default action which was triggered after MouseDown. So it does not solve my issue which would be to avoid this MouseDown event and fire DragStart instead. Sometimes (not very often), when I "MouseDown" while moving the mouse, I get a DragStart event.

Comment: Actually I meant to `preventDefault()` into the `addDragStartHandler` in order to avoid the default action the browser does when you start to drag over a text. Wasn't a direct answer to you question, but a way to let the drag&drop work. The overall idea is wrong though, you can't expect the `DragStartEvent` to work by `preventDefault()` or `stopPropagaton()` the `MouseDownEvent`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your final goal is to drag&drop the `HTML` widget using the native `GWT` drag&drop support (that maps the `HTML5 API`), you are missing some pieces to let the things work. You have to:

- make the element `draggable` (can't see it in your code):

  ```
  theWidget.getElement().setDraggable(Element.DRAGGABLE_TRUE)
  ```
- add a `DragStartHandler` to the element and set the data to transfer (as you did):

  ```
  theWidget.addDragStartHandler(new DragStartHandler() {
    public void onDragStart(DragStartEvent event) {
      event.setData(data, "some data" );
    }
  });
  ```
- add a `DragOverHandler` to an element target, that will be the element to drop onto:

  ```
  targetWidget.addDragOverHandler(new DragOverHandler() {
    public void onDragOver(DragOverEvent event) {
      // Some kind of effect, if you like.
    }
  });
  ```
- add a `DropHandler` to the same element target, prevent the default browser action, and retrieve the data:

  ```
  targetWidget.addDropHandler(new DropHandler() {
    public void onDrop(DropEvent event) {
      event.PreventDefault();
      String data = event.getData("data");  
    }
  });
  ```

Comment: Tx; Actually your code confirms what I had before. I just let the code for the "drag part" in my question. Except for : "theWidget.getElement().setDraggable(Element.DRAGGABLE_TRUE) , which I didn't put because was not necessary for the image widget, and is not either for the HTML widget *** which wometimes does drag depending on the mouse move (hard to get and reproduce). So I am still in need of a solution. Tx anyway.